# Is this a dirac delta function?

Tags: integration, distribution-theory

I had this on an exam yesterday, and I'm not entirely convinced that the statement is true.
We were asked to show that the function $\delta (x) = \int_{-∞}^{∞} \frac{1}{t(t-x)} dt$ is a dirac delta function by demonstrating that $I=\int_{-∞}^{∞} f(x)\delta(x) dx$ holds all the necessary properties.

There are three things I believe should be shown: 1) The function should be infinite at a single point. (this function is infinite at $t=x$)  2)  It should be zero everywhere else 3) It should satisfy $\int_{-∞}^{∞} f(x)\delta(x) dx=f(0)$.

I showed 2 is true by demonstrating that the Cauchy Principal Value is zero for that integral which means that it's zero everywhere save that one point we avoid.... but I don't see how 3 holds in general.  I see that it holds for some functions, like $f(x)=x$, but what about $f(x)=1$, for example.  Anyway, is this a delta function or not.... if so, why?

Comment: No!  See this is a tricky point, lol.  This is a function of $x$!  So we are integrating out the $t$, which means it's NOT a function of $t$ so to say it's infinite at $t=0$ would be a misunderstanding (I believe) in the sense that all one needs to do to compute that integral is go into the complex plane and do a contour integral and get arbitrarily close to $t=0$ and $t=x$.

Comment: Someone deleted their comment, I should point out that I'm not having a conversation with myself.  Previous comment was "isn't it also infinite at t=0?".

Comment: If $g$ is any function that is $0$ except at one point, then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)g(x) dx = 0$, no matter what $f(x)$ is and no matter what $g$ does at that one point. So you cannot possibly prove that your function has the three properties, because no function at all has those three properties.

Comment: The dirac function is *formally* defined by $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\delta(x)dx=f(0)$, but it's not really a function.  It's a measure; the Lebesque integral with respect to $\delta$ returns $f(0)$.

Comment: Okay, but does my function satisfy the requirements to be a Dirac delta? Function or  otherwise? Ie.... Call it a function or whatever, is my thing a Dirac delta.

Comment: Your third requirement is enough by itself provided you say "for all sufficiently well behaved functions $f$" and specificy that that means test functions, or Schwartz functions, or whichever class of functions is appropriate for the occasion.

Comment: @dustanalysis I know that is what you are looking for, which is why I posted a comment instead of an answer.  I wanted to point that out because I found it helpful to understand exactly what $\delta$ *is* before I started proving things about it.

Answer (score 10):

The question as posted is not well defined (due to multiple reasons). The fact that Dirac's $\delta$ is not a function but rather a distribution was pointed out before. What is also (maybe even more) relevant is  that there is no prescription given how to handle the divergency due to the poles at $t=0$ and $t=x$. In fact, the question can be read as: is $I$ defined via
$$I = \int_{-∞}^{∞} \frac{1}{(t+ i \epsilon_1) (t-x+ i \epsilon_2)} dt$$
where $\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2 \to 0$ the $\delta$-distribution. It turns out that the answer to this question depends on the fact whether $\epsilon_1$ (and $\epsilon_2$) approach 0 from above or from below. That this is important is exemplified by [Sokhotski's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokhotski%E2%80%93Plemelj_theorem#Version_for_the_real_line).

To get more insight into the problem, we can apply the partial fraction expansion
$$\frac{1}{(t+ i \epsilon_1) (t-x+ i \epsilon_2)}
= \frac{1}{x+ i(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2) } \left(\frac{1}{t-x+i\epsilon_2}- \frac{1}{t+ i \epsilon_1}
 \right).$$

If we perform the integral over $t$ (which is now possible as we have regularized the integral by the small imaginary parts), we obtain 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{t-x+i\epsilon_2}- \frac{1}{t+ i \epsilon_1}
 \right)dt = \begin{cases} 2\pi i & \epsilon_1 >0 , \epsilon_2 <0,\\
-2\pi i & \epsilon_1 <0 , \epsilon_2 >0,\\
0 & \text{else}.
\end{cases}$$
We see that if $\epsilon_1$ has the same sign as $\epsilon_2$, $I$ cannot be the $\delta$-distribution as it vanishes identically.

For $\epsilon_1 \epsilon_2 <0$, we have
$$I = \frac{2\pi i \mathop{\rm sgn}(\epsilon_1) }{x+ i(\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2) }
= 2\pi i \mathop{\rm sgn}(\epsilon_1) \left( \mathcal{P} \frac{1}{x} 
+ i \pi \mathop{\rm sgn}(\epsilon_2-\epsilon_1) \delta(x)
\right)$$
via Sokhotki's formula.

We see that the distribution defined by $I$ depends very sensitively on the signs and magnitude of $\epsilon_1$ and $\epsilon_2$. And in non of the many different limits it is in fact a simple $\delta$-distribution!

Comment: Nice post, shows typical problems with distributions and the order (or even kind of) limits.

Comment: Can I ask how to evaluate the second integral in you post?

Comment: @Vladimir: the second integral I evaluate using the [Residue theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem) (just choose a contour along the real line and close it with a big semicircle in the upper or lower complex plane).

Comment: Just to add that Sokhotski's formula is frequently attributed to Plemelj. (HTH to ease searches).

Answer (score 4):

This is a charming example! To be able to really *prove* something, it is best to be more circumspect about what the "function" given by the integral "is", since, as noted in comments, it's not a function in a classical (=late 19th century post-Cauchy-Weierstrass) sense, although it is of course very productive to think of it as a generalized (=post-L.Schwartz) function. There are choices. As in the first comment by the OP, we could take $\delta_\epsilon(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty {dt\over (t+i\epsilon)(t+i\epsilon +x)}$, and say that the integral with $\epsilon=0$ is _some_kind_of_ limit as $\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+$. In particular, it is a *weak* limit, meaning that we only require that limits $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\delta_{\epsilon}(x)\,dx\;$ exist for nice-enough functions $f$.

Indeed, for $f(0)=0\;$, this limit certainly exists and is $0$. Assuming that the limit exists in general, this already proves that the limit must be a scalar multiple of $\delta$.

To determine the scalar, and/or to see that the limit exists for all Schwartz functions (for example), the usual trick is to take a specific, convenient $f_o$ with $f_o(0)=1$, and first note that for general $f$ we have $\delta_\epsilon(f)=\delta_\epsilon(f-f(0)\cdot f_o)+f(0)\cdot \delta_\epsilon(f_o)\;$. Thus, it suffices to evaluate $\delta_\epsilon(f_o)$ explicitly. Taking $f_o(x)=e^{-x^2}$ succeeds here...

Answer (score 2):

This is a little bit rough and ready, but could hopefully be tidied up. First, as @paul points out, we need to agree on what we mean by a distribution. I'll be a little less generous and say that it is an object that acts on test functions to give a number. This action takes the form $$<\Delta,u> = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \Delta(x)u(x) \,dx,$$
where $\Delta$ is the distribution and $u$ is a test function - that is, a smooth function ($C^\infty$) which vanishes outside some compact set. (Hence, there is a number $K>0$ such that $u$ and all its derivatives equal zero for $|x|>K$.) We also need to agree that if we can define functions $\Delta_\epsilon, \epsilon>0$ with the property that 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}<\Delta_\epsilon,u> \quad \hbox{exists for all test functions }\,u,$$
then we say that $\Delta=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\Delta_\epsilon$ is a distribution with $$<\Delta,u>=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}<\Delta_\epsilon,u>.$$ (These are standard definitions.)

So taking up your principal value argument, define, for $\epsilon>0$,  $$\delta_\epsilon(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{x-\epsilon}\frac{dt}{t(t-x)}+\int_{x+\epsilon}^{+\infty}\frac{dt}{t(t-x)}.$$ We can calculate that 
$$\delta_\epsilon(x) = \frac{1}{x}\log\left|\frac{x+\epsilon}{x-\epsilon}\right|.$$ [Oops. This doesn't deal correctly with $x=0$, so the rest of this answer is pretty much useless.]

(This - $\delta_\epsilon$ - is locally integrable on $\mathbb{R}$, which is the condition required of the 1-parameter ($\epsilon$) family of functions $\Delta_\epsilon$ above. That is, $\Delta_\epsilon$ is not required to be a classical function, which is useful because $\delta_\epsilon$ blows up at $x=\epsilon$. However the blow-up is very mild.)

So for the programme above to work, we have to check that (i) $<\delta_\epsilon,u>$ exists for all test functions $u$; (ii) the limit $\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}<\delta_\epsilon,u>$ exists. If in addition we can show that this limit evaluates to $cu(0)$ for some constant $c$ and all test functions $u$, we can then legitimately say that $\delta=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\delta_\epsilon$ is indeed equal to $c\delta_{Dirac}=c\times$ the Dirac delta.

So pick a test function $u$. Since $u$ is smooth everywhere, we can apply Taylor's theorem and write $$u(x)=u(0)+u'(0)x+\frac{u''(\xi_x)}{2}x^2,$$
where $\xi_x$ depends continuously on $x$. Then 
$$<\delta_\epsilon,u> = I_1 + I_2 + I_3,$$
where 
\begin{eqnarray*}I_1&=&u(0)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta_\epsilon(x)dx,\\
I_2&=&u'(0)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x\delta_\epsilon(x)dx,\\
I_3&=&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{u''(\xi_x)}{2}x^2\delta_\epsilon(x)dx.\\
\end{eqnarray*}

Notice that $\delta_\epsilon$ is even, so $I_2=0$ and $I_1$ and $I_3$ can be written as integrals over the positive half-line. Now recall that $u$ and its derivatives vanish for all $|x|>K$. Let $M$ be the maximum of the second derivative of $u$ on $[-K,K]$. Then 
$$|I_3|\leq M \int_0^K x^2\delta_\epsilon(x)dx =M\int_0^K x\log\left|\frac{x+\epsilon}{x-\epsilon}\right|dx.$$ 
We can evaluate this explicitly (bit of work...) and show that (i) it exists for $\epsilon>0$ and (ii) vanishes in the limit $\epsilon\to 0$.

It remains to deal with the integral $I_1$. We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{1}{x}\log\left|\frac{x+\epsilon}{x-\epsilon}\right| &=&
\int_0^\epsilon\frac{1}{x}\log\left(\frac{\epsilon+x}{\epsilon-x}\right) + 
\int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{1}{x}\log\left(\frac{x+\epsilon}{x-\epsilon}\right)\\
&=& 2\int_0^1\frac{1}{t}\log\left(\frac{1+t}{1-t}\right)dt,\end{eqnarray*}
by using $x=\epsilon t$ in the first integral and $x=\epsilon/t$ in the second. This integral is finite, with value $c\simeq 4.93$ (probably something much more elegant, but this is what Wolfram Alpha gives).

So for any test function $u$, it seems that 
$$\lim_{\epsilon\to0} <\delta_\epsilon,u> = c u(0),$$
and so your integral is $c\delta_{Dirac}$.

Comment: I am not sure how you integrate $\frac{1}{t(t-x)}$ to obtain the formula for $\delta_\epsilon$? It looks like the function behaves like $t^{-1}$ for $t\approx0$ so the integral does not converge (unless you implicitly assume that you also take the principal value there).

Comment: Yes - I missed that important point. The $\delta_\epsilon(x)$ I used is not defined at $x=0$. A 'double regularization' is required to deal with the problem as you pointed out in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the question again, I noticed that you mention principal value. There is of course another interpretation of your distribution
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{P} \frac{1}{t(t-x)} dt$$
which involves a principle value integral; but the statement of my earlier post remains that the integral as stated in the question is just not well defined such that one is forced to find an interpretation.
${{{}}}$
To prove that $I$ is in fact proportional to the $\delta$-distribution, we introduce
$$\begin{align} I_\epsilon&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \mathcal{P} \frac{1}{t(t-x + i\epsilon)}dt
=\int_{0}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{t(t-x + i\epsilon)} 
+ \frac{1}{t(t+x - i\epsilon)}\right]dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty\frac{2}{t^2 - (x-i \epsilon)^2}\\
&=  \frac{\pi}{i(x-i\epsilon)} \end{align}$$
with $I =  \lim_{\epsilon\to 0} \mathop{\rm Re}I_\epsilon$.

We have $$\mathop{\rm Re}I_e= \frac{\pi \epsilon}{x^2+\epsilon^2} $$
which converges towards 
$$ I = \pi^2 \delta(x).$$

Comment: In this interpretation, the result is follows from the [Poincaré-Bertrand formula](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Poincaré-Bertrand_formula) for an iterated principal value integral.